# How can you access a PromiseValue from a fetch API?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

Sorry new to javascript , but i'm trying to do a fetch api. I'm able to do so, but i'm unable to get the data to use it.  Below is the Html / javascript im using.  It works.  I can console.log and see the promise.

However, i'm unable to get the [[PromiseValue]] 442 value to i can use it in a calculation.

I changed my API on here so it won't work.    thank you in advance.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>my test</h1>
   <h1><div id="currocc"></div></h1> 

</body>



<script>

var y = fetch('https://display.safespace.io/value/live/489f3c')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((val) => document.getElementById('currocc').textContent = val);

console.log(y)

</script>

</html>


from console -----  

Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: 442
```

Comment: Put your code that cares about the value into the .then callback.

Comment: are you purposely trying to put a parsed json object into textContent?  ({}).toString() === "[object Object]" which is surely not what you want

Comment: @user120242 I was reading some place that i had to use json to unwrap the value.